# Toggle button menu in bootstrap not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Toggle button menu in bootstrap not working, instead of that makes my menu shrinks, like is giving a zoom-out. I'm using chrome tool to see how respositive it's, the content is working just fine but the menu is giving me this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?> - <?php bloginfo('description'); ?></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css">



</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="container-fluid" id="navfluid">
       <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigationbar">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo get_home_url() ?>"><?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
       </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigationbar">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
               <li><a href="<?php echo get_home_url() ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="news"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> Blog </a></li>

           </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad was missing the <meta>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the jQuery and the bootstrap.js as well.

bootstrap cdn
https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

jquery cdn
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/

P/S: The `.min.js` or `min.css` is actually the same as the original file just having smaller file size and readability is very low.